# Where does FilledInput inherit backgroundColor property in Mui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was working on Filled Inputs in form of `TextFields` as well as `FilledInput`. I need a solution to make the background color of all the `FilledInput`s, currently, I am using `makeStyle` and adding class names to each component, which seems redundant.

Can someone give a better workaround, like changing some property in the theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [FilledInput API docs](https://material-ui.com/api/filled-input/#component-name) we can learn that:

> The MuiFilledInput name can be used for providing default props or
> style overrides at the theme level.

And from this [this guide in overriding MUI CSS globally](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#css) we can learn to use `overrides` key of the `theme` to potentially change every single style injected by Material-UI into the DOM

Sample Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import FilledInput from "@material-ui/core/FilledInput";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    // Style sheet name
    MuiFilledInput: {
      // Name of the rule
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "orange"
      }
    }
  }
});

function OverridesCss() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <FilledInput placeholder="sample placeholder" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default OverridesCss;
```

[image: Edit React MUI - Global Theme CSS]

Comment: You are a savior, thanks a lot man this changes my whole perspective. It's so powerful feature.